# How to filter the particular three type of file.(.count,.switch,.data)

Tags: c#, datatable

**Added the files in a datatable.**

**Here my problem is i just added the count file first so in first 3 rows count files are added. and in next 3 rows switch files are added.
In first 3 rows switch file and data file columns are empty.it will take the next 3 rows. I need to fill that column in same row.**

Here it filters only count file , need to filter 3 type of files.

```
  string[] Count_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.count", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

For 3 type of file 3 separate for each loop, Please suggest a simple way.
In a directory need to check the 3 type of file in each sub folder, if any type of file is absent need to mention in data table column. And fill the existing file details in data table.

```
  // Getting the latest .Count file:
        var directory = "C:\\MainFolder";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        DataColumn column;
        column = new DataColumn();
        dt.Columns.Add("Count_File_Date", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Count_File_Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Count_File_LMD", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Switch_FileName", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Switch_File_Date", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Data_File_Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Data_File_LMD", typeof(String));

         // Getting the values of count file

        string[] Count_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.count", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


        List<string> Count_Filename = new List<string>();
        DateTime Count_L_M_D;
        string Count_File_Name;


        foreach (string CurrentPath in Count_filePath)
        {
            string Content = File.ReadAllText(@CurrentPath);
            string loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Content.Substring(9, 8), "yyyyMMdd",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            DateTime Datevalue = DateTime.Parse(loadedDate);
            Count_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath);
            Count_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentPath);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row["Count_File_Date"] = Datevalue;
            row["Count_File_Name"] = Count_File_Name;
            row["Count_File_LMD"] = Count_L_M_D;
        }

       // Getting the values of switch file
       string[] Switch_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.switch", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       DateTime Switch_L_M_D;
       string S_File_Name;
       foreach (string CurrentPath in Switch_filePath)
       {
           S_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath);
           Switch_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentPath);

           row = dt.NewRow();
           dt.Rows.Add(row);

           row["Switch_FileName"] = S_File_Name;
           row["Switch_File_Date"] = Switch_L_M_D;
       }

       // Getting the values of data file

       string[] Data_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.data", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       List<DateTime> DataFileLMDate_List = new List<DateTime>();
       List<string> Data_FileName_List = new List<string>();
       DateTime Data_L_M_D;
       string Data_File_Name;

       foreach (string CurrentPath in Switch_filePath)
       {
           Data_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath);
           Data_FileName_List.Add(Data_File_Name);
           Data_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentPath);
           DataFileLMDate_List.Add(Data_L_M_D);

           row = dt.NewRow();
           dt.Rows.Add(row);

           row["Data_File_Name"] = Data_File_Name;
           row["Data_File_LMD"] = Data_L_M_D;
       }
```

Comment: You first need to add columns to the datatable outside of foreach loop.

Comment: Yes !!that too i tried. Outside foreach loop column is added like  column.ColumnName = "Switch_FileName"; and inside assigning value to the column row[column.ColumnName] = S_File_Name; the same issue occurred.

Comment: Doing just doing  `column.ColumnName = "Switch_FileName";` does not add column to the datatable. You need to do `dt.Columns.Add(column);` for both the column.. Read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable

Comment: Yes!!! You are correct. Its working Fine. Thank You Chetan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the datatable does not have any columns. You have `DataColumn column` variable declared but it is never added to the datatable.

You need to add all the necessary columns to the datatable before you can add any rows to it.

In you case you need to create instances of DataColumn type and set their ColumnName property to appropriate values and then add them to the table.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.ColumnName = "Switch_FileName";
dt.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.ColumnName = "Switch_File_Date";
dt.Columns.Add(column);

string[] Switch_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.switch", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
DateTime Switch_L_M_D;
string S_File_Name;

foreach (string CurrentPath in Switch_filePath)
{
   var row = dt.NewRow();
   S_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath);
   Switch_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentPath);

   row["Switch_FileName"] = S_File_Name;
   row["Switch_File_Date"] = Switch_L_M_D;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.